# How to sum the result at the end of table row in react table

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I have a table that shows employee wages detail with values from API multiply by some constant values to get the total wages for each employee.I want to achieve the following; I want to sum the total wages of all the employees as it is and show the result. I have tried using map method and reduce, but I guess I wasn't using it well because it didn't work

I have taken off part of the code to show the action part

`````
  renderTable() {

    var totalCount = 0;
    var shownCount = 0;
    var lowerBound = 0;
    var upperBound = 0;
    var filtered = [];

    filtered = this.state.data.map( (row, i,) => {
      const calWage=row.numberofPresentAttendances * row.wages* 8;
   const calWageOvertime = row.numberofPresentAttendances * [row.wages*8]+row.wages*1.5*row.overtime;


      if(row.department.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.departmentFilter) > -1){
        return (
          <tr key={"employeeData"+i}>
            <td>{i+1}</td>

            <td>{row.name}</td>
            <td>{row.numberofPresentAttendances}</td>
            <td>{row.department}</td>
            <td>{row.wages}</td>
            <td>
            <Link to={"/employee/overtime/"+row._id}>
                <Button className="btn btn-light"><Overtime/></Button>
              </Link>

            </td>
            <td>{row.overtime}</td>
            <td>
              {row.overtime<1?calWage
            : calWageOvertime}

            </td>

          </tr>
        );
      } else {
        return undefined;
      }

````



Any assistance would be appreciated.


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tgnj5.jpg
`````

Answer (score 1):

Add this code after generating `filtered` and before returning it. First we need to do a sum on all the wages, then we add a new row to the table, only with the total fields.

```
const totalWages = this.state.data.map((row) => row.wages).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);  
filtered.push(
    <tr className="totalRow">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        ... // go to the wage td
        <td>{totalWages}</td>
        ...
    </tr>
);
```